# Menu blinking when scrolling using scrollTop()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue, I have two `div`s, `#divOne` and `#divTwo` and I'm trying to make that when scroll is greater or equal to specific height it changes to another menu.

My first menu is in `#divOne` and second in `#divTwo` but when the specific height is reached and keep the scroll in the same position the menu changes many times quickly while I stay with the scroll in the same position

This is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 500) {

        $('#divTwo').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#divOne').addClass('hidden');

    } else {

        $('#divOne').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#divTwo').addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

I think is because when the condition is true `#divOne` has a specific height and the is hidden so the value of `scrollTop` changes lets say for example to 400 and make a kind of weird behavior, I tried adding the height of `#divOne` before to the `scrollTop` but I couldn't make it work, so I'm asking for help to fix this issue or another way to achieve this, I hope you can help me, thanks.

You can see here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1qepst0/3/)

NOTE: I forgot to say that the second menu is fixed.

Comment: In case it helps solve the question, if the scrollTop lands on exactly 503, it triggers a scroll back to 495, which triggers a scroll back to 503, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't recreate it in Edge or Firefox and finally got Chrome to do what you describe.  I changed the check to $(this).scrollTop >= (500 + $('#divTwo').height()).  It was doing exactly what Patrick describes.  Adding the class would change the scrollTop, so it would then remove the class, changing the scrollTop, making it add the class, etc.  It was in a really narrow band of scroll values this would happen.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() { 
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= (200 + $('#divTwo').height())) {

  $('#divTwo').removeClass('hidden');
  $('#divOne').addClass('hidden');

 } else {

  $('#divOne').removeClass('hidden');
  $('#divTwo').addClass('hidden');
 }
});
```

```css
.container { height: 1200px; }

#divOne { background-color: green; color: white; }

#divTwo {background-color: red; color: white; position: fixed; }

.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="divOne">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore ut autem libero dolore animi? Quaerat et quasi enim eius deleniti fuga. Odit ut earum deleniti optio reiciendis non impedit ullam.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="divTwo" class="hidden">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt nemo eius, dolor rerum dolorem reiciendis tenetur perferendis facere, provident obcaecati veritatis reprehenderit illum voluptates velit aliquam cum architecto error! Iusto.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I had to lower the value to 200 in the fiddle to give it enough room to trigger.
https://jsfiddle.net/p1qepst0/6/

Comment: Thank you, this help me to fix this but i have to use the height of `#divOne` no `#divTwo`

Comment: I believe that is a more correct solution.  I'll update the answer to reflect that.  Actually after changing it, it reintroduced some flashing, so I left it as divTwo.

Comment: Had the same issue wih Chrome 70. Adding the height of a div did correct the problem. Thanks for the tip!